# How to plot by category over time

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have two columns, categorical and year, that I am trying to plot. I am trying to take the sum total of each categorical per year to create a multi-class time series plot.

```
ax = data[data.categorical=="cat1"]["categorical"].plot(label='cat1')
data[data.categorical=="cat2"]["categorical"].plot(ax=ax, label='cat3')
data[data.categorical=="cat3"]["categorical"].plot(ax=ax, label='cat3')
plt.xlabel("Year")
plt.ylabel("Number per category")
sns.despine()
```

But am getting an error stating no numeric data to plot. I am looking for something similar to the above, perhaps with `data[data.categorical=="cat3"]["categorical"].lambda x : (1 for x in data.categorical)`

I will use the following lists as examples.

```
categorical = ["cat1","cat1","cat2","cat3","cat2","cat1","cat3","cat2","cat1","cat3","cat3","cat3","cat2","cat1","cat2","cat3","cat2","cat2","cat3","cat1","cat1","cat1","cat3"]

year = [2013,2014,2013,2015,2014,2014,2013,2014,2014,2015,2015,2013,2014,2014,2013,2014,2015,2015,2015,2013,2014,2015,2013]
```

My goal is to obtain something similar to the following picture
[image]

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback error and some sample data?

Comment: Yes, sorry. It should be more clear now.

Comment: It doesn't make sense: `data[data.categorical=="cat2"]["categorical"]` is a series of strings with only `"cat2"` as values. You can't plot that.

Answer (score 5):

I'm hesitant to call this a "solution", as it's basically just a summary of basic Pandas functionality, which is explained in the same documentation where you found the time series plot you've placed in your post.  But seeing as there's some confusion around `groupby` and plotting, a demo may help clear things up.

We can use two calls to `groupby()`.
The first `groupby()` gets a count of category appearances per year, using the `count` aggregation.
The second `groupby()` is used to plot the time series for each category.

To start, generate a sample data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
categorical = ["cat1","cat1","cat2","cat3","cat2","cat1","cat3","cat2",
               "cat1","cat3","cat3","cat3","cat2","cat1","cat2","cat3",
               "cat2","cat2","cat3","cat1","cat1","cat1","cat3"]
year = [2013,2014,2013,2015,2014,2014,2013,2014,2014,2015,2015,2013,
        2014,2014,2013,2014,2015,2015,2015,2013,2014,2015,2013]
df = pd.DataFrame({'categorical':categorical,
                   'year':year})

   categorical  year
 0        cat1  2013
 1        cat1  2014
                 ...
21        cat1  2015
22        cat3  2013
```

Now get counts per category, per year:

```
# reset_index() gives a column for counting, after groupby uses year and category
ctdf = (df.reset_index()
          .groupby(['year','categorical'], as_index=False)
          .count()
          # rename isn't strictly necessary here, it's just for readability
          .rename(columns={'index':'ct'})
       )

   year categorical  ct
0  2013        cat1   2
1  2013        cat2   2
2  2013        cat3   3
3  2014        cat1   5
4  2014        cat2   3
5  2014        cat3   1
6  2015        cat1   1
7  2015        cat2   2
8  2015        cat3   4
```

Finally, plot time series for each category, keyed by color:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# key gives the group name (i.e. category), data gives the actual values
for key, data in ctdf.groupby('categorical'):
    data.plot(x='year', y='ct', ax=ax, label=key)
```

[image: time series plot by category]

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried groupby?

```
df.groupby(["year","categorical"]).count()
```

Comment: Yes I did earlier, but plt.plot(df.groupby(["year","categorical]).count()) returns ''tuple' object is not callable'

Comment: but you should get a dataframe you can work with. So for example, add df["count"] ) df["categorical"] before the groupby. Than after groupby only select cat1 over loc and try to print that one