# Visualizaion of count records of categorical variables including their missing values (`None` or `NaN`)

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, time-series, missing-data

Let's say I have the following time series data dataframe:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random
np.random.seed(2019)

# Generate TS
#rng = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', freq='MS', periods=N)
ts = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', '2000-12-31 23:00', freq='H') #.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')    # freq='MS'set the frequency of date in months and start from day 1. You can use 'T' for minutes and so on

# number of samples
N = len(ts)

# Create a random dataset
data = {
    #"TS": ts,
    'Appx':  [random.choice(['App1', 'App2', 'App3', None]) for _ in range(N)], # generate categorical data including missing data "None"
    'VM':    [random.choice(['VM1' , 'VM2' ]) for _ in range(N)]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=ts)
#df.resample('M').mean().plot()
df
#                       Appx    VM
#2000-01-01 00:00:00    App1    VM2
#2000-01-01 01:00:00    None    VM1
#2000-01-01 02:00:00    None    VM2
#2000-01-01 03:00:00    App3    VM2
#2000-01-01 04:00:00    App1    VM1
#...    ... ...
#2000-12-31 19:00:00    App2    VM1
#2000-12-31 20:00:00    App3    VM1
#2000-12-31 21:00:00    App3    VM1
#2000-12-31 22:00:00    App1    VM1
#2000-12-31 23:00:00    App1    VM1
# 8784 rows × 2 columns
```

After checking other available resources:

- [Plotting categorical data counts over time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27862214/plotting-categorical-data-counts-over-time)
- [How to make a line plot from a dataframe with multiple categorical columns in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65694410/how-to-make-a-line-plot-from-a-dataframe-with-multiple-categorical-columns-in-ma)
- [How to groupby dataframe with categorical variables for making linechart in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63308183/how-to-groupby-dataframe-with-categorical-variables-for-making-linechart-in-matp)
- [How to plot by category over time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43832311/how-to-plot-by-category-over-time)
- [Plot time series on category level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65354689/plot-time-series-on-category-level)
- [Plotting multiple time series after a groupby in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30942755/plotting-multiple-time-series-after-a-groupby-in-pandas)
- [Pandas: plot multiple time series DataFrame into a single plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38197964/pandas-plot-multiple-time-series-dataframe-into-a-single-plot)
- [Plot a line graph with categorical columns for each line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68328524/plot-a-line-graph-with-categorical-columns-for-each-line)

**Problem:** plotting count records of categorical variables including their missing values (`None` or `NaN`) within [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) dataframe

**My tries:**
I tried to plot count records using the following scripts unsuccessfully:
At first, I used a simple example close to what I can depict both data and missing values inspired [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50824069/10452700) by plotting App column records within missing values (dashed line) over time for each desired VM:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

day = ([ 1 , 2 , 3, 4, 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9])
App1 = ([0.6 , 0.8 , np.nan, np.nan, 4 , 6 , 6.5 ,7 , 8])
App2 = ([ 1 , 2 , np.nan, np.nan, 0.5 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10])
App3 = ([ 1.5 , 2.5 , np.nan, np.nan, 3 , 4 , 6 , 8 , 11])

cf = pd.DataFrame({'App1': App1, 'App2': App2, 'App3': App3}, index = day)
cf.index.name = 'day'

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(cf['App1'].fillna(method='ffill'), color='r', ls = '--', lw = 1, label='_nolegend_')
ax.plot(cf['App1'], color='k', lw=1.5, marker = 'v', label='App1',)
line, = ax.plot(cf['App2'].fillna(method='ffill'), color='r', ls = '--', lw = 1, label='_nolegend_')
ax.plot(cf['App2'], color='k', lw=1.5, marker = 's', label='App2')
line, = ax.plot(cf['App3'].fillna(method='ffill'), color='r', ls = '--', lw = 1, label='_nolegend_')
ax.plot(cf['App3'], color='k', lw=1.5, marker = 'o', label='App3')

plt.xlabel('Time Stamp')
plt.ylabel('Record counts')
plt.title('Apps within missing values for VM1')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

---

My outputs so far:

[image: img]

---

But I get error when I apply it to my generated time-series data based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71086101/10452700):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df['Appx'].fillna(value=np.nan, inplace=True)
df['Appx'].astype('category') # or str for string
#df = df.astype(int)


# Filter the DataFrame by a list of string values in the "App1" column
filtered_df  = df[ df["Appx"].isin([np.nan])]
filtered_dff = df[~df["Appx"].isin([np.nan])]


cf = pd.DataFrame({'Appx': filtered_dff["Appx"]}, index = df.index)
#cf.index.name = df.index #'TS'

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(cf['Appx'].fillna(method='ffill'), ls = '--', lw = 1, label='_nolegend_')
ax.plot(cf['Appx'], color=line.get_color(), lw=1.5, marker = 'o')
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=45)
plt.xlabel('TS')
plt.ylabel('mm')
plt.legend('best')
plt.show()
```

> TypeError: 'value' must be an instance of str or bytes, not a float

Even I digged further using `groupby()`:

```py
# reset_index() gives a column for counting, after groupby uses year and category
ctdf = (df.reset_index()
          .groupby(['Appx','VM'], as_index=False)
          .count()
          # rename isn't strictly necessary here, it's just for readability
          .rename(columns={'index':'ct'})
       )
ctdf

#    Appx    VM  ct
#0  App1    VM1 1127
#1  App1    VM2 1084
#2  App2    VM1 1066
#3  App2    VM2 1098
#4  App3    VM1 1084
#5  App3    VM2 1049

df['Appx'].fillna(value=np.nan, inplace=True)
df['Appx'].astype('category') # or str for string
#df = df.astype(int)


# Filter the DataFrame by a list of string values in the "App1" column
filtered_df  = df[ df["Appx"].isin([np.nan])]
#filtered_dff = df[~df["Appx"].isin([np.nan])]

# reset_index() gives a column for counting, after groupby uses year and category
ctdff = (filtered_df
          #.isna()
          .reset_index()
          .groupby(['VM'], as_index=False)
          .count()
          # rename isn't strictly necessary here, it's just for readability
          .rename(columns={'index':'ct'})
       )
ctdff

#   VM   ct   Appx
#0  VM1 1153    0
#1  VM2 1123    0
```

Similar to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59127231/10452700) I might be interested such plot so called `cat_horizontal_plot`:
[image: img]

Note:  I'm not interested in removing or imputing solutions as much as possible:

- [Handling missing categorical values ML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61868829/handling-missing-categorical-values-ml)
- [Applying OneHotEncoding on categorical data with missing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63260772/applying-onehotencoding-on-categorical-data-with-missing-values)
- [replace missing values in categorical data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46120727/replace-missing-values-in-categorical-data)
- [Deal with missing categorical data python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46125486/deal-with-missing-categorical-data-python)

---

In those corner cases I can't show missing values:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.lineplot(data = df, x = df.index, y = 'Appx', hue = 'Appx', marker='o', alpha=0.2)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=[0.5, 1.02], loc='lower center')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

### [image: img]

```py
grouped = df.groupby(['VM','Appx'])

for key, group in grouped:
    data = group.groupby(lambda x: x.hour).count()
    data['Appx'].plot(label=key , legend=True)
```

[image: img]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If the point is to always include the counts for `None` or `NaN`, then convert them to a string.

```py
# convert the None or NaN to a string
df.Appx = df.Appx.fillna('None')

# make the column categorical
df.Appx = pd.Categorical(values=df.Appx, categories=sorted(df.Appx.unique()), ordered=True)
```

### Bar Chart for Monthly Count Aggregation

```py
# separate the dataframe by uniqe VM, and aggreate
vm = {v: df[df.VM.eq(v)].groupby([pd.Grouper(level=0, freq='M'), 'Appx'], observed=False).count().unstack(level=1) for v in sorted(df.VM.unique())}

# plot each VM separately
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize=(10, 10), tight_layout=True, sharex=True)

for ax, key in zip(axes, vm.keys()):

    data = vm[key]['VM']

    data.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax, ylabel='Counts', xlabel='Date', title=f'VM: {key}', rot=0)

    ax.set_xticks(ticks=range(len(data.index)), labels=data.index.strftime('%Y-%m'))
```

[image]

### Proportional Stack Bars

```py
vm = {v: df[df.VM.eq(v)].groupby([pd.Grouper(level=0, freq='M'), 'Appx'], observed=False).count().unstack(level=1) for v in sorted(df.VM.unique())}

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize=(10, 10), tight_layout=True, sharex=True)

for ax, key in zip(axes, vm.keys()):

    data = vm[key]['VM']

    percent = data.div(data.sum(axis=1), axis=0).mul(100).round(1)

    percent.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, ax=ax, ylabel='Counts', xlabel='Date', title=f'VM: {key}', rot=0)

    ax.set_xticks(ticks=range(len(data.index)), labels=data.index.strftime('%Y-%m'))
```

[image]

### Scatter Points for Daily Count Aggregation

```py
# separate the dataframe by uniqe VM, and aggreate
vm = {v: df[df.VM.eq(v)].groupby([pd.Grouper(level=0, freq='d'), 'Appx'], observed=False).count().unstack(level=1) for v in sorted(df.VM.unique())}

# plot each VM separately
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize=(10, 10), tight_layout=True, sharex=True)

for ax, key in zip(axes, vm.keys()):

    data = vm[key]['VM']

    data.plot(ax=ax, ylabel='Counts', xlabel='Date', title=f'VM: {key}', rot=0, linestyle='none', marker='.')
```

[image]

- Iterate through each column to add a different `marker` or `linestyle`.

```py
vm = {v: df[df.VM.eq(v)].groupby([pd.Grouper(level=0, freq='d'), 'Appx'], observed=False).count().unstack(level=1) for v in sorted(df.VM.unique())}

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize=(10, 10), tight_layout=True, sharex=True)

for ax, key in zip(axes, vm.keys()):

    data = vm[key]['VM']

    cols = data.columns

    linestyles = ['-', '-', '-', ':']
    markers = ['d', 'v', 's', '.']

    for col, ls, marker in zip(cols, linestyles, markers):
        data[col].plot(ax=ax, ylabel='Counts', xlabel='Date', title=f'VM: {key}', rot=0, linestyle=ls, marker=marker)

    ax.legend()
```

[image]